# Inverse laplace transform of $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}s}\cdot\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$

Tags: laplace-transform

I want to find the inverse la place transformation of:
$ e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}s}\cdot\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$. I know that the inverse la place transformation of $\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$  is $f(t) =\frac{1}{2}t \sin t$.
I have difficult, however, to exactly find what the exponential changes. I know that it shifts the function $f(t)$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to the right. Would it make that the inverse la place transform equal to:
$ g(t) = H_{\frac{\pi}{2}}(t)\cdot(\frac{1}{2}(t-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin (t-\frac{\pi}{2}))$ with $H$ being the Heaviside function?

I found that the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}H_{\frac{\pi}{2}}(t)\cdot((t-\frac{\pi}{2})\sin (t)-\cos(t))$. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for reading,

K. Kamal

Comment: If there's no $s$ in that factor, then it just passes through unchanged. But from what you're saying here it sounds like you intend $e^{-\pi s/2}$.

Comment: @Ian You're correct.

Comment: @Jack Huh? The partial fraction decomposition of $s/(s^2+1)^2$ is $s/(s^2+1)^2=s/(s^2+1)^2$. Hard to see how that's going to help...

Comment: @K. Kamal: Your result is corrrect I think there is a typo in the second (given answer) one while writing  $\sin(t-\pi/2)=-\cos t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solving a more general problem:

$$\text{f}_{\space\alpha,\beta}\left(t\right):=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}\right)\cdot\frac{\text{s}}{\left(\beta+\text{s}^2\right)^2}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Using the '[convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)' property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\text{f}_{\space\alpha,\beta}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{s}}{\left(\beta+\text{s}^2\right)^2}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag2$$

Using the '[delayed impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms)' in the table of the [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$\text{f}_{\space\alpha,\beta}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\delta\left(t-\tau+\alpha\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{s}}{\left(\beta+\text{s}^2\right)^2}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\tag3$$

And:

$$\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\text{s}}{\left(\beta+\text{s}^2\right)^2}\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}=\frac{\tau\cdot\sin\left(\tau\cdot\sqrt{\beta}\right)}{2\cdot\sqrt{\beta}}\tag4$$

So, we get:

$$\text{f}_{\space\alpha,\beta}\left(t\right)=\int_0^t\delta\left(t-\tau+\alpha\right)\cdot\frac{\tau\cdot\sin\left(\tau\cdot\sqrt{\beta}\right)}{2\cdot\sqrt{\beta}}\space\text{d}\tau=$$
$$\frac{1}{2\cdot\sqrt{\beta}}\cdot\int_0^t\delta\left(t-\tau+\alpha\right)\cdot\tau\cdot\sin\left(\tau\cdot\sqrt{\beta}\right)\space\text{d}\tau\tag5$$